# JavaScript function inside a JSP page not working properly

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am using Javascript function inside a JSP page for input field validation.
The javacsript function is not working properly .

I am using multiple if conditions inside the javacsript function. 
Even when I am leaving the fields blank the control is moving to next page.

I cannot use a normal HTML page as I would be doing some more processing on this page , that is why I have used JSP.

The input field validation is not working .
I even tried to retrieve the elements  Id  but still the code is not working.

Below is my code:-

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>

<title>First Page</title>
<script language="javascript">
function required()  
{  
var empt = document.forms["form1"]["Iname"].value;
var empt1 = document.forms["form1"]["Iemail"].value;
if (empt == "")  
{  
alert("Please input a Value in name field");  
return false;  
}  

if (empt1 == "")  
{  
alert("Please input a Value in email field");  
return false;  
} 

if(empt1 != "")
{
    var x = document.forms["form1"]["Iemail"].value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
       alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
} 


else
    {
    return true;
    }

} 


</script>
</head>

<body>


 <form  name ="form1" action="Insert1"  OnSubmit="return required()"  method="post" >
   Name:   <input type="text" name="Iname"> <br/>

   Email:    <input type="text" name="Iemail"> <br/><br/>

   <INPUT type = "submit" name="Submit" value = "Insert User"  />

</form> 

<br> <br/> <br/> 

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed a closing bracket in your Javascript function. 
*Use proper indentation to to avoid these errors*

```
function required()  
{  
        var empt = document.forms["form1"]["Iname"].value;
        var empt1 = document.forms["form1"]["Iemail"].value;
        if (empt == "")  
        {  
            alert("Please input a Value in name field");  
            return false;  
        }  
        if (empt1 == "")  
        {  
            alert("Please input a Value in email field");  
            return false;  
        } 
        if(empt1 != "")
        {
            var x = document.forms["form1"]["Iemail"].value;
            var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
            var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
            if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
                alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
                return false;
            } 
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
}
```